# Input queue callback called but no data

Tags: objective-c, macos, audio, core-audio, macos-sierra

In an effort to start getting into macOS programming, I'm trying to make a simple program that would record audio from an input device (eg. the built-in microphone on my MacBook Pro). I have created a Objective-C Cocoa project in Xcode and the code is a slightly adapted version of [this tutorial from developer.apple.com.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/AQRecord/RecordingAudio.html)

Here's my code:

```
// AppDelegate.m:  

#include <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>  

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {  

     struct AQRecorderState S;  

#define PRINT_R do{\  
printf("%d: r = %d\n",__LINE__, r);\  
}while(0)  

    AudioStreamBasicDescription *fmt = &S.mDataFormat;  

    fmt->mFormatID         = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;  
    fmt->mSampleRate       = 44100.0;  
    fmt->mChannelsPerFrame = 1;  
    fmt->mBitsPerChannel   = 32;  
    fmt->mBytesPerFrame    = fmt->mChannelsPerFrame * sizeof (float);  
    fmt->mFramesPerPacket  = 1;  
    fmt->mBytesPerPacket   = fmt->mBytesPerFrame * fmt->mFramesPerPacket;  
    fmt->mFormatFlags      = kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat | kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved;  

    OSStatus r = 0;  

    r = AudioQueueNewInput(&S.mDataFormat, HandleInputBuffer, &S, NULL, kCFRunLoopCommonModes, 0, &S.mQueue);  

    PRINT_R;  

    UInt32 dataFormatSize = sizeof (S.mDataFormat);  

    r = AudioQueueGetProperty (  
                       S.mQueue,  
                       kAudioConverterCurrentInputStreamDescription,  
                       &S.mDataFormat,  
                       &dataFormatSize  
                       );  

    S.bufferByteSize = 22050;      

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_BUFFERS; ++i) {        
        r = AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(S.mQueue, S.bufferByteSize, &S.mBuffers[i]);  
        PRINT_R;  

        r = AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(S.mQueue, S.mBuffers[i], 0, NULL);  
        PRINT_R;  
    }  

    S.mCurrentPacket = 0;        
    S.mIsRunning = true;        

    r = AudioQueueStart(S.mQueue, NULL);  
    PRINT_R;  

    r = AudioQueueStop(S.mQueue, true);  
    S.mIsRunning = false;  

    PRINT_R;  

    r = AudioQueueDispose(S.mQueue, true);  
}
```

Here's my input callback function (defined in a separate C file):

```
void HandleInputBuffer (  
                           void                                *aqData,             
                           AudioQueueRef                       inAQ,                
                           AudioQueueBufferRef                 inBuffer,            
                           const AudioTimeStamp                *inStartTime,        
                           UInt32                              inNumPackets,        
                           const AudioStreamPacketDescription  *inPacketDesc          
) {  

    struct AQRecorderState *pAqData = (struct AQRecorderState *) aqData;               

    if (inNumPackets == 0 && pAqData->mDataFormat.mBytesPerPacket != 0) {  
        inNumPackets =  
        inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize / pAqData->mDataFormat.mBytesPerPacket;  
    }  
    printf("%f\n", *(float*)inBuffer->mAudioData);  
    if (pAqData->mIsRunning == 0)                                      
        return;  

    AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(pAqData->mQueue, inBuffer, 0, NULL);  
}
```

When the program is run, all of the Core Audio function calls return 0, which (I believe) represents "no error", and HandleInputBuffer is called NUM_BUFFERS times in a very rapid succession or almost instantly (most definitely not every 0.5 secs like the buffer size of 22050 would suggest at this sample rate), and all the first samples are 0.0. What am I missing here?

Comment: My C gets rusted. Don't you have to allocate/`malloc` `S`? Also the formats values look somehow arbitrary to me. Why 32 bit/channel? Why those formatFlags?

Comment: Oh right, when calling `AudioQueueNewInput` with invalid values set into the ASBD, an error message ("fmt?") is given that includes the default input device's default values, and that's where I got the values from. Also, I believe `AudioQueueAllocateBuffer` is doing the allocation

Comment: `AudioQueueNewInput` works with `fmt->mBitsPerChannel = 16` and `fmt->mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger` but still no input. I do kinda wonder why it says "io: 44100 Hz, 32-bit Float" for the built-in microphone though

Comment: If you link to a runnable example, I can have a look.

Comment: `git clone http://github.com/elipp/inputqueue.git` =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`S.bufferByteSize` is in bytes, not frames, so 22050 bytes is not half a second, but `22050/sizeof(float)` frames, so about an eighth of a second.

If you want half a second, try

```
S.bufferByteSize = fmt->mSampleRate * fmt->mBytesPerFrame / 2;
```

In your above code (and also in the git repo you linked), you immediately `AudioQueueStop` and `AudioQueueDispose` the audio queue after `AudioQueueStart`ing it. Don't do that.

Comment: Quite true, thanks! But won't solve my problem unfortunately :( The callback is still called `NUM_BUFFERS` times instantaneously and no data is received.

Comment: Have you looked at the NSLog time stamps? How do you know there's no data?

Comment: Yeah, I have. For example they looked like this when I last ran it: `2017-01-16 02:47:11.439407`, `2017-01-16 02:47:11.439440`, `2017-01-16 02:47:11.439462`, `2017-01-16 02:47:11.439473`, `2017-01-16 02:47:11.439483`, `2017-01-16 02:47:11.439492` with `NUM_BUFFERS = 6` and `bufferByteSize = 44100 * 4`

Comment: Those are pretty close together. Do you have a repo I can look at?

Comment: Okay, so I just misinterpreted the comment (on the original apple sample code) saying "wait on the user interface thread"; I was assuming `AudioQueueStop` waits on the queue to finish. Problem solved XD

Comment: all's well that ends well. happy to help